# how define trigger in mysql for update comments count in another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table a post table and comments table.

```
post_tbl
id    comment_count

comments 
id    post_id   parent_id   comment
```

I want write trigger when a comment inserted in comments table for a special post the post comment_count increase 1unit.

also for delete comments i need comment_count decrease 1 unit.
and if comment parent is NULL it;s mean it's root comment and maybe it's have reply and i need if root comments deleted it's child should be delete and effect post comment_count.

I want do it with trigger, how can i write trigger for this?

Comment: @Heyyou no, i don't.

Comment: All could be done using trigger however you can not delete record from the same table using trigger on which trigger is running, example in case of parent_id null you want to delete all the comments with the same post_id and this is not allowed using the trigger running on the same table.